# How to create a NAT adapter on windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, nat, window

I would like to share my internet connection using the built-in windows10 wifi hotspot. Unfortunately it does not work if I just select Ethernet as the shared connection. Maybe the Connection Sharing is disabled in the network. So I would like to create a NAT adapter on my windows PC, and share the internet connection from that adapter. But I don't know how to create one. All I've found are VMWare or Virtualbox tutorials.

***Note***: Sharing my internet connection in the dormitory is permitted, If only my devices can connect, and use my internet access. But the administrators will not help creating it

---

**Edit**

Result of `NETSH WLAN show drivers`:

```
Interface name: Wi-Fi

Driver                    : TP-LINK Wireless PCI Express Adapter
Vendor                    : TP-LINK
Provider                  : TP-LINK
Date                      : 2012. 09. 19.
Version                   : 10.0.0.209
INF file                  : oem25.inf
Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
Hosted network supported  : Yes
Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            Vendor defined  TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            Vendor defined  CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
Wireless Display Supported: No (Graphics Driver: No, Wi-Fi Driver: No)
```

Result of `NETSH WLAN show hostednetwork`:

```
Hosted network settings
-----------------------
    Mode                   : Allowed
    SSID name              : "Your_SSID"
    Max number of clients  : 100
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP

Hosted network status
---------------------
    Status                 : Started
    BSSID                  : 56:16:f9:4f:d7:98
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Channel                : 11
    Number of clients      : 0
```

Comment: No. I would like to share the Ethernet connection using the TP-Link wifi adapter

Comment: Run, `NETSH WLAN show drivers` in an elevated command prompt, and provide the output to the command.  Be sure you either provide a screenshot which has been uploaded to imgur or be sure to format the output so it's readable.

Comment: I edited the question with the results

Comment: Have you tried making an ad-hoc connection?

Comment: You have run both `NETSH WLAN set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Your_SSID key=Your_Passphrase` and `NETSH WLAN start hostednetwork`?  You have also shared the ethernet connection [correct](https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/medium/public/field/image/2016/02/internet-connection-sharing-windows-10.jpg?itok=59GJr5U0)?  What is the output of, `NETSH WLAN show hostednetwork`, update your question.

Comment: Yes, I tried to enable ad-hoc mode in the adapter settings. I updated the question